# Raspberry Pi Home Automation (HUB)

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, home-automation

I have been experimenting with home home automation and want to turn my raspberry pi 3 into a hub not something my devices manually connect to e.g from the gpio pins. In many unsuccessful attempts I have tried OpenHab. I would like to mount a touchscreen with a GUI so I can e.g turn the lights on from this control panel instead of via phone or other hubs available like Google Home. If anyone knows how I might do this it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [home-assistant](https://home-assistant.io) with [floorplan](https://github.com/pkozul/ha-floorplan) would work for this. It takes a little bit of configuring but well worth it.